# Unable to access clipboard in FileSystemWatcher's renamed event

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, desktop-application, clipboard

I have an object of FileSystemWatcher called 'watcher' instantiated in my main function. I tried to store the text on clipboard in a string variable during the 'watcher.renamed' event but it always returns empty data? I checked the value of the variable with the help of a breakpoint, it remains empty.

Here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Application.StartupPath;
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(Application.StartupPath+ @"\RBsTurn.txt");
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Renamed);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = Clipboard.GetText();
        MessageBox.Show(x);
    }
```

This code, always displays an empty text box when the file is renamed.. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure there's data available on the clipboard?

Comment: yep.. the event was not getting access to clipboard. STA properties had to be set, solution is posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clipboard` access methods must be initiated from an STA thread in order to function properly. Unfortunately, the `FileSystemWatcher` runs its callbacks on threadpool threads, all of which are part of the MTA. As such, trying to access the clipboard isn't going to work in your example.

If you need to perform some UI work when your event handler is run, then you'll need to notify the form (or some other piece of the UI) about that. You can use the `Form` object's `BeginInvoke()` method to post a method to run on the UI thread:

```
void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        string x = Clipboard.GetText();
        MessageBox.Show(x);
    }));
}
```

Comment: you are right about the STA thing.. I tried something which worked. Just posting the solution :)

Comment: The odd thing is, [the MSDN documentation for `Clipboard.GetText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that it throws `ThreadStateException` if: `"The current thread is not in single-threaded apartment (STA) mode."` which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I believe it *used* to, but no longer does. It appears the documentation has not kept pace.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to create a new thread in the event handler and set its STA properties

Here is the code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Application.StartupPath;
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(Application.StartupPath+ @"\RBsTurn.txt");
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Renamed);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
        });

        th.IsBackground = true;
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
     }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I know this works, but it seems like overkill to start a new thread every time a file system event comes in. Why not just marshal to the UI thread?

Comment: aye! you are right, I eventually ended up using your method :)